# In DynamoDB ,given a table, can I programmatically find the primary keys( both hash key and sort key)

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, primary-key

I am new to this and using python and boto3. I get a table in dynamodb as follows

```py
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('MyTabe')
```

Now I want to execute a Query for which I need the primary key. Is it possible to find these keys programmatically? ( PS I know the keys or I can even find it from AWS interactively)

Answer (score 0):

You can find keys by .scan() method, like:

```
response = client.scan(
    TableName='your_table_name')

for item in response['Items']:
     print(item.get('your_primary_keys'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution . I have a question though( I am a newbie here)...scan() is a very expensive way to get the primary keys right? I was trying to model a generic function so that it can work for any table. Will it be is better to hardcode the keys for each table than to use scan?scan

Comment: @nandita you right, so you can run scan with attributes, where you can put non primary key=value to get items